# Query posts by post type, author and post meta

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, users, author, count

Bit of an awkward one here, and there may not be a solutions within current WP core.

Basically I have a CPT called "connection" with a custom meta field called "outcome" which stores an integer.

I'd like to list the sum of all "outcome" fields on all "connection" posts, by author.

E.g. **User 1** has authored **10** "connections", with their combined "outcome" field equalling **[int]**.

I know how to list the number of "connections" authored, with `count_user_posts( $user->ID , 'connection' );` but am stuck on the rest.

I've tried doing post queries, but that didn't seem to be the right direction as it lists each individual post whereas I'm needing to combine totals and metadata.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you query for posts, you don't have to output HTML in the loop, you can just retrieve the data you want and process it. There isn't a function or API that will do this for you and your instinct is incorrect. You had the right idea the first time

Comment: @TomJNowell I see, thank you! So it's possible to use queries without splitting the results into individual posts? E.g. I could query 'connection' type posts, and get all combined 'outcome' metadata that way? But then I'd still need to only combine posts by the same author.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to combine them. Just use a counter variable and loop over each post, e.g. `counter = 0; foreach post { get this posts value and add it to counter }`. What you are doing is not something that can or should be done as a single step.

Comment: Ah sorry, it's because the "outcomes" field contains a different integer for each post, so I'm wanting to add those up for each author.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, you still need to request those posts via `WP_Query`, then fetch each individual outcomes field and add them up in PHP, as I said in my first and second comments, there is no API to do that in a single function call.

Comment: That's fine, I wasn't expecting a single function - sorry for not making that clear. Thanks for giving me a better idea of the direction I should be looking in though.